# Time evolution of a quantum field via classical field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

**How do quantum fields evolve in time? (Heisenberg Picture)**

**How does time evolution relate to the (E-L) equations of motion?**

I’ve had this understanding that there is a duality between classical and quantum fields:

*Take the fourier transform of a classical field, multiply it by creation operators, and then fourier transform back to get a corresponding quantum field.*

**Now here is my picture of time-evolution (*):**
We evolve a quantum field by going to its corresponding classical field, evolve the classical field (via the equations of motion), and then find the corresponding quantum field. Keep in mind that this is all using the creation operators of the free field.

However, in many QFT textbooks, ***the correspondence between quantum and classical fields is a function of time***. This is because the creation operators are a function of time. So "My picture of time evolution (*)" is wrong in some way! What is the correct picture?
I’ve had this idea of how to remedy the situation:

If $\hat a_{\mathbf{k}}^\dagger$ is the quantum field corresponding to the classical field $\varphi(\mathbf{x},0)=e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x}}$,

then, $\hat a_{\mathbf{k}}^\dagger(t)$ is the quantum field corresponding to the classical field $\varphi(\mathbf{x},t)$, where $\varphi(\mathbf{x},t)$ is obtained by applying the equations of motion (E-L) to the classical field  $\varphi(\mathbf{x},0)$.

That is, $\hat a_{\mathbf{k}}^\dagger(t)$ is just $\hat a_{\mathbf{k}}^\dagger$ evolved in time in the sense according to “My picture of time evolution (*)". Because of the superposition principle, this would validate my picture of time evolution, because all fields can be represented by their fourier transforms, and time evolution is linear.

If this is also wrong, then *how else can the equations of a motion of a classical field dictate the evolution of a quantum field?*

Comment: What "time evolution" is depends on whether you want to look at it in the Schrödinger, Heisenberg or interaction picture. Which are you looking at? (The fact that you want to evolve the fields excludes the Schrödinger picture, but the other two remain open)

Comment: I would say the Heisenberg picture.

Comment: Quantum "time evolution" is "unitary", meaning that the time (duration) parameter merely changes the phase of the quantum states (Schrodiger picture) or the phase of observables (Heisenberg picture). Actual "evolution" (meaning actual change of state) happens on a quantum  measurement (measurement problem)

Comment: @NikosM.: So the Higgs doesn't really show up in the collisions of the LHC beams, it only happens because ATLAS and CMS are surrounding the intersection points? If I turn the power off on either of my detectors, would there be any Higgs created?

Comment: @CuriousOne, i think you misunderstand my comment, that's why i did not mention "measurement paradox" (as it would imply your comment) but "measurement problem". let's not take this as to the reality of QM here. Still the my comment holds as a quantum measurement represents an actual change of state vs a change of phase

Comment: @NikosM.: Careful with these statements about phases - even in the Schrödinger picture, only *Hamiltonian eigenstates* evolve only with a phase, others are actually changing. And in the Heisenberg picture, the action of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}Ht}$ from the left and its conjugate from the right on the observable is *far* from being *just a phase* in the general setting.

Comment: @NikosM. Quantum states are not complex numbers, but vectors of the Hilbert space. Two vectors of the Hilbert space may have the same norm but be very different!

Comment: @NikosM.: I know what you mean but it's very dangerous to make this argument about measurements in high energy scenarios when laymen are present, they may misunderstand. By the time the outgoing particles arrive at high energy detectors, the "measurement" has taken place, already, the correlation length of these processes is much, much smaller than the size of the detectors.

Comment: @ACuriousMind yes correct, energy (hamiltonian) eignestates have this behavior (still these sattes are used in most representations)

Comment: @NikosM.: The coherent states of the quantum harmonic oscillator are *the* example for non-trivial time evolution of a quantum state.

Comment: @CuriousOne, and yuggib, really i do not agree at all about "making statements when laymen are around". i would prefer these statements over others (which mislead in other ways)

Comment: @NikosM.: Seriously, a high energy physics experiment IS NOT a model system for which the quantum measurement problem applies. The particles coming out of the intersection points are, for all practical purposes, already reduced to classical billiard balls (non-withstanding the use of magnetic fields and coherent effects like Cherenkov radiation in the detectors). Much of the non-trivial physics, including the decoherence, all happens within a volume smaller than a proton (there are exceptions for secondary decays of long lived intermediaries, but those aren't coherent, either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is but one truth about time evolution in quantum mechanics:

*The Hamiltonian is the generator of time translations.*

In the Heisenberg picture, this means we directly borrow the quantized<sup>1</sup> version of the evolution of observables on phase space, i.e.

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}A(\vec x,t) = \mathrm{i}[H,A(\vec x, t)]$$

holds for all operators/operator-valued distributions on the Hilbert space of our QFT. Now, solving this equation yields (see also [BCH-formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma))

$$ A(\vec x,t) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}H(t-t_0)} A(\vec x,t_0) \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H(t-t_0)} $$

From this, it follows that the fields, which *are* operator-valued distributions, also must evolve like this. Since we implemented the quantized version of the classical time evolution, it follows that the classical equations of motion implied by it also hold for the quantum fields *as an operator equation*.

But nowhere here did we ever *need* classical pictures. We don't even care if $H$ comes from quantizing a classical system or if we just made it up. Quantum physics - and especially QFT - works without *any* recourse to the classical world. And that is *good*, because the classical world is supposed to *emerge* in certain limits from the quantum theory, which is more fundamental and has a broader range of phenomena.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here, quantization means replacing the Poisson bracket $\{\dot{},\dot{}\}$ by the commutator $\mathrm{i}[\dot{},\dot{}]$.

Comment: I suppose it might be worth pointing out that you've set $\hbar=1$ here without explicitly stating it.

Answer (score 5):

Simply, the classical evolution ***does not*** dictate quantum evolution.

In a suitable sense (I have no time of explaining it here in details) you can obtain the classical dynamics from the quantum dynamics (even in a rigorous mathematical fashion in some cases) in the limit $\hslash\to 0$.

So it is really the contrary of what you say. This is actually natural: it is common folklore that classical dynamics is just an approximation of quantum dynamics when the quantum effects are negligible ***and not vice versa***.

Properties of the classical dynamics (such as symmetries, dispersive effects...) may have a quantum counterpart, and thus their study is important. Nevertheless, having a well-defined classical dynamics is not sufficient to define a corresponding quantum dynamics.

Comment: But the equations of motion of a quantum field are obtained via classical field theory (i.e. E-L equation)! Also, just the mere fact that we discuss "scalar" fields means that the dynamics are of $\phi:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}$, not some operator valued distribution.

Comment: Context may help here: I'm trying to follow my book's derivation of the LSZ formula. The book discusses classical field theory first, and then writes Lagrangians for quantum systems and expects us to infer that everything just transfers over.

Comment: The equation of motion of a quantum field are not obtained via the classical theory. Why do you think it is the case? In most of the realistic cases, QFT hamiltonians are not mathematically well defined. And that is a problem indeed. Nevertheless (at least when it is well-defined, or in theories with cut offs), it is the quantum Hamiltonian that generates the quantum dynamics (even of quantum fields obviously).

Comment: At least with the free-quantum field, the E-L equations are satisfied. (i.e. $(\square+m^2)\phi=0$). So the principle of least action holds at least in this case.

Comment: "Why do I think it is the case"? Because we obtain the equations of motion via the E-L equation. At least in the free theory.

Comment: @Dave: the physics at the interaction points of a particle collision (which is the main type of experiment that we are interested in) does not follow a "large energy" approximation. Indeed, the volume in which it happens and the timescale on which it happens are determined by the energy of the collisions, therefor the uncertainty is of the order 1 and we need to look at the full quantum fields. You are right, nobody cares about that during the detection of the outgoing particles, though, they are indeed "classical".

Comment: @Dave But these is the free classical equation of motion. And $\Phi$, as you write it, is a classical field. Maybe you are making a bit of confusion. The dynamics of the corresponding field operator, is dictated by the Heisenberg equation $i\partial_t \hat{\Phi}=[\hat{\Phi},H]$, where $H$ is the quantum Hamiltonian.

Comment: In Quantum Optics, in the Heisenberg picture, you can take the Heisenberg equation and derive from it an equation of motion for the operators of the quantum field.  This equation turns out to be the same as the equation of motion for the classical field.  (Of course, that is only true because the field is non-interacting.)